# Problem running winusb in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, usb, windows, winusb

I want to install winusb program i am [following the steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu/381560#381560) but I fail to run it. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening.

ps If there is another program like winusb, so that I can burn windows in a usb memory stick through ubuntu, I would be more than glad to hear it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having problems with the PPA because the program has not yet been released for version 15.10 of Ubuntu.  It may take some time (months(?)) before it is recompiled for Wily.

A solution would be to load a VM with an earlier version of Ubuntu, and run WinUSB in that earlier version.